# Questions regarding invertible matrices and basis

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $f: V \to V$ be a linear operator on the finite-dimensional real vector space V. Let B be a basis for V. Let A be the real matrix which represents $f$ with respect to B.

(a) $f$ is invertible if and only if $f(B)$ is a basis for $V$.

So suppose $f$ is invertible. By definition of invertible, then there exists some matrix $C$ such that $f(B)C = Cf(B) = I$. I don't really know where to go from here... I suppose that I need to show that $f(B)$ spans $V$ and linear independence. I don't really know the notation for how to do this or how to draw this conclusion from the fact that $f$ is invertible.

(b) $f$ is invertible if and only if $A$ is an invertible matrix.

By definition $A$ represents $f$ with respect to $B$ and it's a given the $f$ is invertible so obviously $A$ should be to. I don't get what I'm trying to prove here... or how to do it.

I'm having a lot of difficulty with this as my text is very ambiguous with the definitions relating to linear operators. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a)Suppose that $f(B)$ is a basis for $V$. Then, for every $x \in V$, $x = \sum x_i f(B_i)$, where $B_i$ are the columns of $B$.

Now, because $f$ is linear, $x = \sum x_i f(B_i) = \sum f(x_iB_i) = f(\sum x_iB_i)$. Now, every element $x \in V$ is in the image of $f$. Hence, $f$ is onto.

Furthermore, I claim $f$ is one-one. Suppose that $f(x)=f(y)$. Then, $f(\sum x_iB_i) = f(\sum y_iB_i)$. Expanding, $\sum x_if(B_i) = \sum y_if(B_i)$, and taking to the other side, $\sum (x_i-y_i)f(B_i) = 0$ .

Because this is a linear combination of the $f(B_i)$ which is zero, and the $f(B_i)$ are linearly independent because they form a basis, it follows that $x_i-y_i=0$ for all $i$, or that $x_i=y_i$ for all $i$, giving $x=y$.

Hence, $f$ is one-one, hence it is invertible.

The other way: Suppose that $f$ has an inverse $f^{-1}$. Then, most importantly, $f$ is onto and one-one. We want to show that $f(B_i)$ forms a basis for $V$. It is enough to show it is linearly independent, because it already has $n$ elements.

Now, suppose that $\sum x_i f(B_i) = 0$ is a linear combination. Then, using the linearity of $f$, this evaluates to $f( \sum x_i B_i) = 0$. Since $f$ is one-one,  $\sum x_i B_i = 0$. Since the $B_i$ are linearly independent, $x_i =0$. Hence, the $f(B_i)$ are  linearly independent, and a set of cardinality $n$. Hence, they form a basis for $V$.

b) Suppose that $A = f(B)$ is invertible. Then, there is some matrix $C$ such that $CA=AC = I$.Then, let $g(v)=Cv$ for any $v \in V$ be a function, which is a linear operator. It is easy to see that $fg(v) = gf(v) = v$. Hence, $f$ is invertible.

The converse is similar. I'll leave it to you.

Comment: $B$ is a basis, however, not a matrix. Unless we're in $\Bbb R^n$, with a canonical basis, there's no way to turn $B$ into a matrix.

Comment: @TedShifrin I assumed we were in $\mathbb{R^n}$. After all, we have that $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$.

Comment: That isomorphism amounts to a choice of basis. You should just let $v_1,\dots,v_n$ be the elements of the basis and argue exactly as you did. Similarly, $A=f(B)$ is nonsense. You, too, need to review what the matrix of a linear map with respect to a basis is. You must write $f(v_i) = \sum a_{ji}v_j$.

Comment: So what does, "matrix of a linear map with respect to a basis," mean? My book doesn't define it (among a million other things), and google search is yielding nothing. Why even bother saying anything about $A$ if we have to write it as Mr. Shifrin said? I feel like this question is ambiguously worded just for the sake of being complicated. I'm really trying to understand what is going on here. The answer doesn't matter if I have no concept.

Comment: @Nid: I answered this question at the end of my previous comment. The $i$th column of $A$ is the coefficient vector of $T(v_i)$ ($v_i$ being the $i$th basis vector) with respect to the basis $B$. But I think all you really need to know here is that composition of linear maps corresponds to multiplication of their corresponding matrices.

Answer (score 3):

**HINTS**:

(1) Can you show that an invertible linear map sends linearly independent vectors to linearly independent vectors? Then dimension will do the rest for you.

(2) If $f$ is invertible and $A$ is the matrix representing $f$ with respect to $B$, can you guess what matrix might be its inverse?

Comment: (1) I have no idea what you mean by this. $f(B) = A$  So since $B$ is linearly independent then $A$ is linearly independent? What about the span; Don't I have to show that $f(B) = A$ spans $V$? What do you mean the dimension will do the rest?

(2) So $B$ is the inverse of $A$? $BA = AB = I$?

Comment: You need to *prove* *either* that when you apply $f$ to the vectors in $B$ you get vectors that are linearly independent *or* that when you apply $f$ to the vectors in $B$ you get vectors that span. $B$ already has a meaning, so it is not a matrix. Knowing that $f$ is invertible means that you have a linear map $f^{-1}$. Can you use this?

Comment: Oh, and $f(B)=A$? No. You need to look up in your text what it means for $A$ to be the matrix of $f$ with respect to the basis $B$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I had to look  twice. I have read your most famous text, "Multivariable calculus". It is one of the standard textbooks prescribed for an online course. I can't believe I'm coming fact to face with you. I'm honoured, sir.

Comment: My text book is pretty bad. It doesn't even say what that means and it just assumes that we know a lot of things. It's my first time taking abstract. A lot of things like linear operators isn't even defined in the book. It just assumes that we know what that means some how.

Comment: I understand how to do the second part. But for the first part, I think I might be interpreting this wrong. We are showing that if $f$ is one to one and onto, then it has an inverse?